# Почему не выполняется обработчик события клика по кнопке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я использую плагин *lightcase* для модальных окон. Когда я нажимаю на определённую кнопку, всплывает окно. Плагин вставляет определённую вёрстку в конец `body`, которая появляется только после щелчка на кнопке, т.е. появляется модальное окно. Я хочу сделать свою кнопку закрытия модального окна. Для этого я вешаю обработчик события клика по этой кнопке в `$(document).ready(...)`, но событие клика по кнопке не работает даже если открыто модальное окно. Как нужно объявить обработчик события в этом случае?

Вот этот код вставляется в содержимое модального окна:

```
<div class="edit editUserName">
...
<div class="popup" id="editNamePopup">
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
  <div class="close">
</div>
```

...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.editUserName').click(function(){
            lightcase.start();
      });
      $('.popup .close').click(function(){
        //Вот эта функция и не выполняется
      })
    })
<script>
```

Comment: можете сделать пример на jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

*Если после нажатия кнопки отображения модального окна код модального окна добавляется в код страницы, то событие может не выполняться, т.к. оно не работает для новых(динамически создаваемых) элементов.*

Поэтому вместо кода:

```
$('.popup .close').click(function(){
    //Вот эта функция и не выполняется
})
```

Используйте код:

```
$(document).on("click",".popup .close", function(){
    /*.....*/
})
```

**Вариант 2:**

*Если код модального окна плагин вставляет сразу на страницу, а не после нажатия кнопки показа модального окна, можно использовать следующий код:*

```
$(".popup .close").on("click", function(){
  /*.....*/
})
```

**UPD**:

*Оригинальный плагин вставляет код формы в блок `lightcase-contentInner` после нажатия на кнопку показа формы([пример модального окна на ajax](http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/#various2)), поэтому, если Вы хотите расположить кнопку в создаваемой форме, используйте **Вариант 1**, предложенный выше.*

Answer (score 1):

В момент готовности документа кнопки еще не существует, поэтому нужно использовать не "click", а "live":

```
$('.popup .close').live("click", function(){
    //Вот эта функция и не выполняется
    })
```

http://jquery-docs.ru/Events/live/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: _live_ `version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9`, поэтому лучше _on_ но все зависит от версии используемой библиотеки

Comment: Действительно, какой же я ненимательный